# Difficulty in understanding the USB interfacing for Altera DE 2

Tags: usb, intel-fpga, usb-host

So I am planning to establish connection between my mouse and the USB Host port of the Altera DE-2 board. As per the documentation the Altera DE-2 board uses the Philips ISP1362 chip which follows the USB 2.0 specifications. I searched in the web for some sufficient documents on how the connection is made. It seems that I need to write a specific software driver for detection of my mouse and further exchange mechanism for the flow of data from my mouse to the FPGA. I am planning to display the Mouse pointer position on the VGA. It will be helpful in getting some pathway in which I can proceed to complete this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Terasic always provides tests / control panels / example projects for all their boards.

Go to Terasic website, find the DE2 board page (in phased out products section), download the DE2 SystemCD (DE2 CD-ROM, whatever), there are demonstration projects, tutorials, all documents and datasheets. Start with their examples and get the first understanding of the approach.

Comment: I have tried out the usb paintbrush example they carried out in the documentation. But they didn't provide the intuition behind the coding and just wrote the Verilog code files. That's why I can't grasp the method in which it works